# Join an Active Directory domain with Linux without being an Administrator

Tags: linux, domain, active-directory, opensuse-13.1

My current task is to configure a *testing* virtual machine to join our company's AD domain, so users can login with domain credentials.

I am only responsible to make **tests** with that VM, that will be used as a sandbox for migrating some company services to a better-performing infrastructure, for example SVN (upgrading our CVS repo) and an internal wiki.

**I am not** an Administrator of the AD controller, and my boss explicitly said that everything I do with the test machine, which is under the control of a common employee, **must** be done without having access to the great power of `Administrator` login.

I installed openSUSE 13.1 from `SuSE Studio`, logged in as `root` and tried to [follow a tutorial](https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/html/openSUSE_121/opensuse-security/cha.security.ad.html#fig.ad.join1) to join the VM to the domain.

The problem is that the tutorial supposes the Linux user has Administrator credentials for AD controller, which is not the case. I have my own credentials, but I'm not an admin. And I must complete the procedure without admin credentials (our IT person might configure a "production" machine based on my configuration only after the demo gets approved).

#### I remember that

during my last job I needed no Admin credentials to join an AD domain with Windows 7. I simply used my own credentials when requested, and any coworker could log in with his/her own credentials.

### What I tried so far:

Using YaST, I entered `Windows Domain Membership`, typed the domain name `DOMAIN.IT` in the Domain or Workgroup

[image: YaST AD]

When I was asked to join the domain, I chose `YES`, then entered my own domain credentials and left `Machine Account OU` default.

[image: YaST AD]

I rebooted the system with `init 6` and the time for login came. First, let me say that in Linux I have typed `DOMAIN.IT` as domain, but in Windows machines we do use `DOMAIN\name.surname` accounts (case insensitive).

With XShell SSH client, I tried the following usernames with the right password:

- name.surname
- domain\name.surname
- domain.it\name.surname
- DOMAIN\name.surname
- DOMAIN.IT\name.surname

All failed.

### How do I log in correctly after YaST said I'm a member of the domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I learnt that the correct and complete answer is no necessary the following:

In YaST's `User & Group Manager` I enabled LDAP/AD login, which was disabled earlier. Then I have set up NTP synchronization with our local NTP source.

But in the Windows world it is a universal constant that **either** any user can join a computer to the network, and then LDAP configuration in Linux *can* ben performed, **or** the user must be granted authority to join machines to AD (for example, be group of a support staff).

Otherwise this **cannot** be done without Administrator credentials.